# jQuery ajax returning 'Object Object'

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send data to a PHP script using jQuery Ajax. For some reason the Ajax request is throwing up an error and returning the following data from the PHP script - `[object Object]`

I've copied my code in below. I've also copied code using the exact same method elsewhere on the page which seems to work fine!

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Firstly, the code that is working fine

**jQuery**

```
 $("#reqtable a").click(function(){
  var cells = []; 
  var name;
  var account;
  var module;
  var email;
  $(this).parent().parent().find("td").each(function(){
  cells.push($(this).html());
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find("input").each(function(){
  email = $(this).val();
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().prop('id', 'die');
  name = cells[0];
  account = cells[1];
  module = cells [2];

  $.ajax({
            url: "release.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {name: name, account: account, module: module, email: email},
            success: function(){
            $("#die").remove();
           }
         });
 });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include('../../dbconnect.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$account = $_POST['account'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$module = $_POST['module'];

$releasequery = "INSERT INTO release_assignment(name, account, email, module) VALUES ('$name', '$account', '$email', '$module')";
$release = $conn->query($releasequery);

$erasequery = "DELETE FROM request_assignment WHERE email='$email' AND module = $module";
$erase = $conn->query($erasequery);

?>
```

And now the code that IS NOT working.

**jQuery**

```
 $("#downloadtable a").click(function(){
  var dlcells = []; 
  var dlname;
  var dlaccount;
  var dlmodule;
  var dlemail;
  var dlsub;
  var dlpath;

  $(this).parent().parent().find("td").each(function(){
  dlcells.push($(this).html());
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find("input.dlemail").each(function(){
  dlemail = $(this).val();
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find("input.dlsub").each(function(){
  dlsub = $(this).val();
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find("input.dlpath").each(function(){
  dlpath = $(this).val();
  });

  $(this).parent().parent().prop('id', 'die2');
  dlname = dlcells[0];
  dlaccount = dlcells[1];
  dlmodule = dlcells [2];

  $.ajax({
            url: "download.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {dlname: dlname, dlaccount: dlaccount, dlmodule: dlmodule, dlemail: dlemail, dlsub: dlsub, dlpath: dlpath},
            success: function(data){
            $("#die2").remove();
            },
            error: function(data){
             $('#downloaddiv').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
            }
         });
 });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include('../../dbconnect.php');

$name = $_POST['dlname'];
$email = $_POST['dlemail'];
$account = $_POST['dlaccount'];
$module = $_POST['dlmodule'];
$path = $_POST['dlpath'];
$submission = $_POST['dlsub'];

$feedbackquery = "INSERT INTO feedback_assignments(name, email, level, unit, assignmentpath, submission) VALUES ('$name', $email, '$account', '$module', '$path', '$submission')";
$feedback = $conn->query($feedbackquery);

$erasequery = "DELETE FROM uploaded_assignments WHERE email='$email' AND unit = $module";
$erase = $conn->query($erasequery);

?>
```

When I comment out all the PHP code and simply put `echo ($_POST['dlname']);` it returns the data `[object Object]`

Can anyone explain what is going on and why it seems to work with one block of code but not the other?

Thanks!

Chris

**Update:** It might be worth mentioning that the initial link `('#downloadtable a')` actually instigates a file download as well as the ajax call, whereas in the code that is working it simply makes the ajax call and nothing else. I don't know if this is throwing a spanner in the works but thought it worth mentioning.

**Update 2:** Using the jQuery Ajax error callback as described below I'm getting the following response:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} 
AJAX error: error :
```

The code I've used in the error callback is as follows:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
   console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
   }
```

Unfortunately I don't understand what this means. Can anyone shed any light on this?

**Update 3** OK, I've found the reason for Ajax blowing up on me, and it relates to update number 1 (above). Basically because the link is to a file download (a .docx file) it seems to be causing the problem with ajax. When I change the link to `href='#'` instead of `href="document.docx"`, the ajax and PHP script works.

This throws up a new question, of course - how can I get the link to download the file whilst simultaneously updating the database?

Comment: `echo ($_POST['dlname']);` why enclosed in parenths? Try this one `echo $_POST['dlname'];`

Comment: What happens if you add `echo "success"` to the end of the PHP script?

Comment: @Anthony Nothing - the script doesn't get that far. I think the problem lies somewhere in the Ajax script but I don't know where. At the moment it is defaulting to the 'error' callback - I've updated the original post to explain this

Comment: @Chris The `success` and `error` callbacks shouldn't be executed until *after* the request has been sent to the server and a response has been retrieved, though.

Comment: @Anthony Does that mean that the error lies with the PHP script? Or is it that the values transmitted by Ajax are not recognised by PHP - they should be simple text values held in each of the jQuery variables

Comment: Even if I comment out everything in the PHP script except `echo "success"` I still get the same error as described in **Update 2** above

Comment: Just to clarify, my PHP error log is not showing any problems either! This really is a mystery!

Comment: View the request in your browser console (Firebug or Chrome developer tools). From the Network tab you´ll be able to view the request and its HTTP Status code and more.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a [`dataType`](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) and use [`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console) to debug your data response.

Also, notice that the `error` callback contains the following arguments and not any "data";

> **error** Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

**Update**

The target file `download.php` might be throwing an exception. Possibly because of some missing quotes around `$email` on the line;

`$feedbackquery = "INSERT INTO feedback_assignments(name, email, level, unit, assignmentpath, submission) VALUES ('$name', $email, '$account', '$module', '$path', '$submission')";`

Debug `download.php` and make sure it generates the expected output/response.

I advice you to escape the values you are using to build your SQL query with to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Which datatype should I use? Data should purely be text which will be inserted into a database, but according to jQuery documentation the only choices are: xml, html, script and json. Also, I've now changed the error function to: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
 }` which returns the following : `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}  and AJAX error: error : ` - Unfortunately I don't have a clue what any of this means, can you help?

Comment: In their code `data` is the name of the parameter to which the value of the first argument (a `jqXhr` object) is passed. When that object is concatenated with strings - `'<p>' + data + '</p>'` - there's an implicit call to the objects `.toString()` function, which returns `[Object object]`.

Comment: @Stefan - I've corrected the PHP script to include the missing quotes, but it hasn't worked. Point taken about escaping the values, I'll add that in once I've resolved this issue.