# Don't understand jQuery Ajax error messages

Tags: jquery

I've posted a question on here ([jQuery ajax returning 'Object Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383680/jquery-ajax-returning-object-object)) and following the advice of one of the answers I've tried playing around with the jQuery Ajax 'Error' responses. Below is the code that I used followed by the response on the console, but I don't understand what they mean. Can anyone shed any light on this (or on my original question?)

Thanks!

**My Code**

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR)); 
 console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown); 
 }
```

**The console return**

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
AJAX error: error :
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the parameters passed to the function is described as follows:

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.

The first argument is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest. You can read more about jqXHR [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and XMLHttpRequest [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest).

The second argument describes what kind of error your'e dealing with.

The third (optional) argument will contain information about a HTTP status if a HTTP error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for that, it helps a little, but I'm still unclear as to what the returns actually mean. What is meant by the string returned by jqXHR (`{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`) and what does it mean that the 'textStatus' is simply returning as 'error'?

Comment: You can read more about XMLHttpRequest and it's properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest). `readyState`, `responseText`, `status` and `statusText` is all documented. I've updated my answer as well.